# How to decode GSM-TCAP messages using asn1c generated code

Tags: parsing, gsm, asn.1, ss7

I am using the c code generated by asn1c from the TCAP protocol specification (i.e., the corresponding [ASN1 files](http://git.osmocom.org/libosmo-asn1-tcap/tree/asn)).
I can successfully encode TCAP packets by the generated code.
However, trying to "decode" related byte streams fails.

A sample code is as follows.

```
// A real byte stream of a TCAP message:
unsigned char packet_bytes[] = {
  0x62, 0x43, 0x48, 0x04, 0x00, 0x18, 0x02, 0x78,
  0x6b, 0x1a, 0x28, 0x18, 0x06, 0x07, 0x00, 0x11,
  0x86, 0x05, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xa0, 0x0d, 0x60,
  0x0b, 0xa1, 0x09, 0x06, 0x07, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x01, 0x00, 0x14, 0x03, 0x6c, 0x1f, 0xa1, 0x1d,
  0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x01, 0x2d, 0x30, 0x15,
  0x80, 0x07, 0x91, 0x64, 0x21, 0x92, 0x05, 0x31,
  0x74, 0x81, 0x01, 0x01, 0x82, 0x07, 0x91, 0x64,
  0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90, 0x02
};
// Initializing ...
TCAP_TCMessage_t _pdu, *pdu = &_pdu;
memset(pdu, 0, sizeof(*pdu));    

// Decoding:
asn_dec_rval_t dec_ret = ber_decode(NULL, &asn_DEF_TCAP_TCMessage, (void **) &pdu, packet_bytes, sizeof(packet_bytes));
```

While the message type ("Begin", in this case), is correctly detected, but other paramters are not parsed.

Using other encoding rules, i.e., `aper_decode()` and `uper_decode()`, also fails.
I would be thankful if anyone can describe how to use the auto-generated c code for decoding (parsing) a byte string of TCAP messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vasil, thank you very much for your answer.

> Which asn1c are you using (git commit id) and where do you get it
>   from as there are quite a log of forks out there?

I use the [mouse07410's branch](https://github.com/mouse07410/asn1c).

> How do you know that Begin is correctly detected?

From the field `present` of the `pdu` variable that is evaluated by ber_decode (you can see the `pdu` type in the sample code).
From the "Wireshark" output for this byte stream, I know that the correct type of the message is `Begin`.

> You could try compiling with -DASN_EMIT_DEBUG=1 in CFLAGS (or
>   -DEMIT_ASN_DEBUG=1 depending on the asn1c version you are using) to get some more debug messages.

Thanks for providing the hint; it was helpful.

---

The problem was related to the asn1 files I was using. 
I used [osmocom asn1 files](https://git.osmocom.org/libosmo-asn1-tcap/tree/asn) and compiled them by

```
ASN=../asn
asn1c $ASN/DialoguePDUs.asn $ASN/tcap.asn $ASN/UnidialoguePDUs.asn
```

in which, `DialoguePortion` is defined as follows (note that the first definition is commented):

```
--DialoguePortion ::= [APPLICATION 11] EXPLICIT EXTERNAL

-- WS adaptation
DialoguePortion ::= [APPLICATION  11] IMPLICIT DialogueOC
DialogueOC ::= OCTET STRING
```

To be able to decode TCAP messages,
one needs to use the former definition (as is in the [standard](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Q.773)), i.e., `DialoguePortion` should be defined as

```
DialoguePortion ::= [APPLICATION 11] EXPLICIT EXTERNAL
```

When using this latter definition in the asn1 file,
and recompiling the asn1 files, the problem solved.

P.S.: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106512/decodingtcap-message-dialogueportion) is also related to my problem.

Comment: Thanks for describing the fix. Please report this to osmocom as well.

Comment: @Vasil, how can we report it to osmocom?

Comment: Post a message to openbsc mailing list https://lists.osmocom.org/mailman/listinfo/openbsc or open a new issue in their bug tracker https://osmocom.org/issues/new (not quite sure in which project).

Answer (score 0):

> I am using the c code generated by asn1c from the TCAP protocol specification

Which asn1c are you using (git commit id) and where do you get it from as there are quite a log of forks out there?

> While the message type ("Begin", in this case), is correctly detected, but other paramters are not parsed.

How do you know that Begin is correctly detected?

> Using other encoding rules, i.e., aper_decode() and uper_decode(), also fails.

There is no point in trying other encodings as they are not binary compatible.

> I would be thankful if anyone can describe how to use the auto-generated c code for decoding (parsing) a byte string of TCAP messages.

You are using it correctly and probably there is a bug somewhere in the BER decoder.

You could try compiling with `-DASN_EMIT_DEBUG=1` in `CFLAGS` (or `-DEMIT_ASN_DEBUG=1` depending on the `asn1c` version you are using) to get some more debug messages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I finally solve the problem, and add my solution.